# How to grep rows that have value less than 0.2 in a specific column?

Tags: linux, grep

```
  ID RT      EZ    Z0      Z1      Z2    RHO     PHE 

 1889  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.8765  -1  
 1890  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.4567  -1  
 1891  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0012  -1  
 1892  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1011  -1
```

I would like to grep all the IDs that have column `RHO` with value less than `0.2`, and the other columns are included for the selected rows.

I am a total newbie regarding this. Please help me :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22556923/1030675

Comment: This has been answered in SO a few minutes ago.

Comment: This question has been crossposted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF && $7<0.2' test.txt
1891  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0012  -1
1892  UN    NA  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1011  -1
```

This prints non-empty lines whose seventh column is numerically lower than `0.2`.

Comment: Hi Adrian! Thank you so much. That command works just fine! God bless you! :)